# how to reset to a specific commit?

Tags: git, version-control, gerrit

I have the following recent commits when I do "git log --oneline"...I want to reset to "8ec2027",I tried some rebase commands that didnot work..what is the exact command to do this?

```
2503013 code: cs release 1.2.3.47
269ed14 code: Fixed below issues due to which 2nd client is not associating to GO
dca02a3 code: Donot allow the scan during WPS/EAPOL exchange.
b2fee57 code: MCC Adaptive Scheduler
6af29c4 code: Not able to connect more then 10 STA
150aacd code: Fix the Max Tx power value in 5G band and .ini support for 11h
8ec2027 Merge "code: cs release 1.2.3.46"
9015b60 Merge "code: Quarky Support on Prima"
......
```

Comment: Does `git reset --hard 8ec2027` what you want?

Comment: I knew that's what he meant and edited the title.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You want to reset not rebase. Rebasing is the act of replaying commits. Resetting is making the current commit some other one.

you will need to save any work that you may have in your work directory first:

```
 git stash -u
```

then you will make you current commit the one you want with

```
git reset --hard 8ec2027
```

Optionally, after you can save where you were before doing this with:

```
git branch -b temp HEAD@{1}
```

see reflog documentation to see how this works.

Comment: if i want to reset to a specific commit..what will stash -u save?am trying to understand how git stash -u is useful before reset?

Comment: It will save uncommitted changes, that is modifications to files in the working dir introduced after your last `git commit` command.

Answer (score 3):

Probably this could also work out for you

1. Create a new branch at 2503013 (this saves the changes after 8ec202)
2. git reset --hard 8ec2027

Comment: `git revert` reverts, not resets

Comment: oops sorry, that's my bad!

`git reset --hard 8ec2027`