# Reverting changes after pulling

Tags: git

I have been working on dev branch, made a couple of commits and pushes, now I merged this branch into master. I want to make a `git pull` on the production server, but what if something won't work after that? Is there a way to revert the changes and come back to where it was before `git pull`?

Comment: Assuming you have no unstaged changes, note down the commit and just reset to that commit if you need to?

Comment: As an aside, there are deployment solutions that solve this and other problems, such as Capistrano, Fabric, and others. http://williamdurand.fr/2012/02/25/deploying-with-git/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at answer for this question: [how to reset to a specific commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14314596/how-to-reset-to-a-specific-commit). I think that's what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

If you did a non-fastforward merge of `dev` into `master` (i.e. you created a merge commit "Merge dev into master"), you can reset to the commit before the merge using `git reset --hard HEAD^`. If you did a fast-forward merge (i.e. there is no "Merge dev into master" commit) you can reset to the state before the pull using `git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD`, assuming you did nothing else after the pull. The latter can be used even in the first case, but it may be more intuitive to use `git reset --hard HEAD^`.